# Php vs .htaccess: what is the best way to prevent access to php files?

Tags: php, file, .htaccess

I'd like to know what is the best practise to prevent access to all php files except the index.php and a few others. I know you can do it by checking the values of a costant in php or via the .htaccess file. But what is the best way in terms of performance and good coding practices?
Thanks

EDIT: I mean prevent read and execute access to the public

Comment: Prevent access to who? Read access? Execute access?

Comment: About .htaccess files... First of all, they are Apache only, and even in Apache, they are frowned upon because of the performance penalty they inflict, due to the fact that they are read for every. single. request. Then, if the configuration accidentally sets `AllowOverride` to `none`, they won't be interpreted at all, leaving the files exposed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best practice is to simply not put your application code in your web server's doc root.  Have a single `index.php` in the root that handles instantiating controllers to do all of the work.  All the rest of your code doesn't have to be directly accessible as long as the index.php can include it.

Comment: So I'll have to rewrite all the require and include?

Comment: Yes.  You should probably be using a lazy loader anyway, so if you aren't, now is a good time to write one.

Comment: Ok thanks. For the rest is this solution the same of "Niet the Dark Absol"?

Comment: @user1315621 Niet is suggesting the exact same thing I am.  Your doc root (`public_html` in his example) is separate from where the application code is (`phpincludes` in his example).

Comment: Thanks. I select your answer because of this help and because you answered a little before.

Comment: @user1315621 I don't mind, but I actually answered 14 seconds before Brad ;)

Comment: Ops. What should I do now? Sorry :D

Answer (score 2):

Don't put PHP files in the web root.

For instance:

```
phpincludes
   - database.php
   - file123.php
   - functions.php
public_html
   - index.php
   - otherstuffhere.php
```

Can't access what's not there!